# Mask AWS S3 Website URL with domain name registered at Google Domains

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns

I created a website in an amazon s3 bucket. It has a nasty URL. I bought a domain name with Google domains. I've configured forwarding on Google's site. When I type mysite.com, it takes me to the website, but it shows the nasty URL, rather than the domain name I bought. Is it possible to hide the nasty AWS S3 domain name and fully mask it with my Google domain name?

Comment: how have you added the name? was it a `A` or `CNAME` record

Comment: It's not possible unless the S3 bucket's name is exactly the same as your domain name. For example if your domain name is `example.com` then the name of the S3 bucket would have to be `example.com`. S3 will only serve a custom domain for a bucket if that domain matches the S3 bucket name. There are ways to get around this if you want to place a CDN in front of the S3 bucket, but with only the services you are currently using there is no way around it.

Comment: @user3788685 FWIW, it's probably not what you'd anticipate.  "Forwarding" a domain usually involves an intermediate, auto-configured web server doing either `3xx` redirect or some sketchy Javascript/iframe madness, the latter not being accepted as a best practice any more (assuming it ever really was), and the former behaving as described -- rewriting the browser's address bar.  For non Route 53 DNS hosting, only a CNAME to S3 is supported, since S3 does not assign fixed IP addresses to buckets or endpoints, and the bucket name must match the hostname unless a CDN does a rewrite, as described.

Comment: Thanks. My bucket is named exactly the same as my domain name. I've done a "permanent redirect (301)" via Google Domains and set it to forward the path. Still not hiding the nasty URL.